# variable table_array in excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim tableref As String
'get cluster number from cel 0,-2
cluster_num = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)
'path to named range in wb elementenbundel
tableref = "elementenbundel.xlsm!" & "table_" & cluster_num
'add colum tag to path
tablecol = "=" & tableref & "[Code]"

Set wb_1 = ThisWorkbook
'open wb elementenbundel
Set wb_2 = Workbooks.Open(wb_1.Path + "/elementenbundel.xlsm")
wb_1.Activate

'create defined name for the range
RangeName = "code_" & cluster_num
'MsgBox (RangeName)
'MsgBox (tablecol)

'if name not present, add named range referring to column of table in elementenbundel
If RangeExists(RangeName) Then
MsgBox (RangeName & " exists")
Else
MsgBox (RangeName & " does not exists")
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=tablecol
End If

'delete previous validation
ActiveCell.Validation.Delete

'insert validation depending on value in A15, B15 will hold "code_" & A15.value
'B15 will be used in the formula to populate the dropdown with the first column of the table in elementenbundel
ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Formula1:="=INDIRECT(B15)"

'look for data in elementenbundel to display in current table
Dim formula As String
formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & ActiveCell.Address & "," & tableref & ", 2)"


ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).formula = formula
```

the above code works

I would like to change the VLOOKUP formula in such a way that users don't have to run the macro.
at the moment the macro grabs the value to put in tableref, but I prefer the formula takes over the value, so I am looking for something like this

```
formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & ActiveCell.Address & ",elementenbundel.xlsm!table_"& CONTENT OF CELL A15 & ", 2)"
```

the result will be that if A15 holds 1:

- the dropdown will be populated with table_1 of elementenbundel
- the VLOOKUP should be looking for the value in table_1, column 2 that
  matches the selected value of the dropdown? thus adding A15.value to the formula

But I don't have a clue how to add this "cell.value" in this formula

Any help would be great!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `OtherCell.Value`?

Comment: Unfortunately this gives "syntax error"

Comment: got it!!

formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & ActiveCell.Address & ",INDIRECT(""elementenbundel.xlsm!table_"" & A15), 2)"

Answer (score 0):

`formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & ActiveCell.Address & ",INDIRECT(""elementenbundel.xlsm!table_"" & A15), 2)`